# Fields is undefined in nextjs from contentful CMS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, contentful

When I fetch data in Contentful CMS API there is an error that tell "fields is undefined" although when I console log it the data had showed

Of example when I const a specific prop form fields like `title` the title will show in the web but don't show the image because I must add `fields` in syntax.

This is featching code:

```js
const client = createClient({
  space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY,
})

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const { items } = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'articles',
    'fields.slug': params.slug
  })

  if (!items.length) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }

  const res = await client.getEntries({ content_type: "articles" })

  return {
    props: { article: items[0], cards: res.items },
    revalidate: 1
  }
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "articles"
  })

  const paths = res.items.map(item => {
    const slug = item.fields.slug

    return {
      params: { slug }
    }
  })

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true
  }
}
```

The only problem is about `fields`

This is the log:

```js
[
   fields: {
      title: 'ارتفاع سعر النفط أربعة أيام على التوالي لأول مرة منذ شهرين',
      slug: 'artfaa-sar-alnft-arbah-ayam-ala-altwaly-lawl-mrh-mnth-shhryn',
      subtitle: 'تحسن الرؤية المستقبلية مع تخفيف الصين قيود مكافحة كوفيد',
      category: 'الطاقة',
      author: [Object],
      createdAt: '2022-12-02T12:39+02:00',
      image: [Object],
      tag: [Array],
      content: [Object]
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you have an example data set to share? If we only look at the code, we won't be able to tell if there's a misspelling, incorrect data type, incorrect casing, or something else that's an issue.

Comment: I wish it will a misspelling but I checked the spelling I found it were same